# Batch apex causing an issue

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

Can anyone help me out in writing batch apex that will create or update records.I never worked on batch apex so struggling here I have two objects

1) SIS_Staging__c

2) Contact

Both objects are having same field Siscode__c, so on inserting records in SIS_Staging__c, I need to check if any contact records are having same Siscode__c or not, if yes then I need to update else I need to create Contact.

I tried below code but when I run batch apex in anonymous window then I am getting below error.

"Constructor not defined: [BatchSISstagingObject].()"

My code is below.

```
global class BatchSISstagingObject implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
List <SIS_Staging__c> mapSisobject = new List <SIS_Staging__c> ();
List <Contact> contactlist1 = new List <Contact> ();

global BatchSISstagingObject(List <SIS_Staging__c> sisobjectUpdate) {
    mapSisobject=sisobjectUpdate;

}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, SIS_Student_ID__c
                                     FROM Contact
                                    ]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC , List <Contact> contactlist) {
    for (SIS_Staging__c acct : mapSisobject){ 
        for (Contact con : contactList){
            if (con.SIS_Student_ID__c == acct.Name){
                    contactlist1.add(new Contact(
                        Id = con.Id,
                        FirstName = acct.First_Name__c,
                        LastName = acct.Last_Name__c
                       ));
                }
        }   
    }

     update contactlist1;
} 
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}

 }
```

Comment: You can perform the update operation from `SIS_Staging__c` trigger and might not need a batch here.

Comment: @rahulgawale, thanks for involving but i need to do with batch apex as records will come from external system to SIS_Staging__c object, I need to have this process to trigger at a specified time so I went with batch apex

Comment: In that case, write the batch on `SIS_Staging__c ` and query contacts inside the execute method based on `SIS_Staging__c` records

Comment: I did the same thing I believe in my code but when I run the code in anonymous window then I am getting  error- "Constructor not defined: [BatchSISstagingObject].()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your batch class, The error "Constructor not defined" seems like you are not passing the right Constructor parameter to the batchclass.

please make sure you are passing constructor parameter while executing the batch from anonymous window. see the below example

```
 List<SIS_Staging__c> SIS_StagingList = new List<SIS_Staging>();
 SIS_StagingList  =[SELECT Id, Name, First_Name__c,Last_Name__c FROM SIS_Staging__c LIMIT 20];
 Database.executeBatch(new BatchSISstagingObject(SIS_StagingList),200);
```